# How to actively update HTML on checkbox status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have `<input type="checkbox" id="box1" />` and <`div id="createhere"></div>` and in a javascript file I have:

```
function(){
    var box=document.getElementById("box").checked;
    var s = "";
    if(box){
        s = "<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />"
        document.getElementById("createhere").innerHTML = s;
    }else{
        s = "";
        document.getElementById("createhere").innerHTML = s;
    }
}
```

Now this works BUT it only creates the text box when I refresh the browser(firefox).

How can I do the same without refreshing the browser?

Comment: `s = '<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />'`

Comment: Can you check all the answers ?

Comment: My code is working, i answered your question first and it got downvote plus not accepted answer. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Really i don't view your answer, i keep the pc few minutes, please post it another time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code work on jQuery. I used jQuery because question has a jQuery tag!

You could try this.

```
$("#box").on('change', function(){

    var check = $(this).prop("checked");
    var inputHTML = "";

    if ( check )
        inputHTML = "<input type='text' name='text' id='text' />";

    $("#createhere").html( inputHTML );

}).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a change event handler

```js
function update() {
  var box = document.getElementById("box").checked;
  var s = "";
  if (box) {
    s = '<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />';
  } else {
    s = "";
  }
  document.getElementById("createhere").innerHTML = s;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="box" onchange="update()" />
<div id="createhere"></div>
```

---

With jQuery

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#box').change(function() {
    $('#createhere').html(this.checked ? '<input type="text" name="text" id="text" />' : '');
  }).change()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="box" />
<div id="createhere"></div>
```